# Aligning multiple texts center if one is null

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I want to align two texts to be centered vertically to the start of the TaskCard. It works as intended if there are two texts present. However, if there is only one and the other one is null the null one will completely disappear, but will still leave a blank space in its place. How do I get rid of it so I can properly align the text?

[image: Image of the issue and the desired fix]

```
@Composable
fun TaskCard(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    task: Task,
    viewModel: TaskListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    Card(
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant
        ), modifier = modifier.padding()
    ) {
        Surface(
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant, modifier = modifier
        ) {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, modifier = modifier.padding(12.dp)

            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .padding(12.dp)
                ) {
                    task.categoryName?.let {
                        Text(
                            text = it,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                        )
                    }
                    Text(
                        text = task.taskName,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineSmall,
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                    )
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = { viewModel.onEvent(TaskListEvent.OnEditTask(task)) },
                    modifier = modifier.size(36.dp)
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Edit,
                        contentDescription = "Edit",
                        modifier = modifier.padding(horizontal = 2.dp),
                        tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                    )
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = { }, modifier = modifier.size(36.dp)
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Notifications,
                        contentDescription = "Notifications",
                        modifier = modifier.padding(horizontal = 2.dp),
                        tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `categoryName` is `null`? It seems empty not null.

Comment: I have marked it nullable in my Entity: `@Entity
data class Task(val taskName: String, val categoryName: String?, @PrimaryKey val id: Int? = null)`

Comment: Ok it can be nullable but it can also contain an empty value. Try to change `task.categoryName?.let` to `if ( !task.categoryName.isNullOrEmpty())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Gabriele Mariotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016562/gabriele-mariotti) suggested I've changed the condition under which the code is executed.

from:

```
task.categoryName?.let
```

to:

```
if (!task.categoryName.isNullOrEmpty())
```